# How to dynamically populate queue lookup according to user role?

Tags: visualforce

I have a built a VR to prevent users from assigning Cases to queues that their Role is not assigned to. However it would nice to override the Change Owner page with a custom solution that only shows the queues that have been assigned to their Role. Is this possible? I'm not looking for code, just a brief explanation would be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: A picture or an example will be great for understanding

Comment: You cannot override the Change Owner page.

Comment: @AdrianLarson - A custom VF page will suffice as we may access the page from a custom button or action etc..

Comment: @SantanuBoral - When you change owner, you have an option for User or Queue. If you select Queue you will see all queues in the org, even if your User Role  only has access to a small number of the total queues.